# Guest addition already installed in Linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have recently installed Linux Mint 14 on a VirtualBox VM and it seems that guest additions are already installed. I did not install them. How is this possible? Does Linux Mint know that it is running inside a VM and install them itself?

Comment: Did you install it from a Ubuntu/Debian/Mint repo?

Comment: Sorry I meant the virtualbox package itself on the actual host.

Comment: I installed it from Ubuntu Software center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear this is automatically done with any Linux Mint install:

- http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=132087

*excerpt*

> Re: Virtualbox guest additions - installation problem
>
> by xenopeek on Wed Apr 24, 2013 3:21 pm
>
> Linux Mint comes with VirtualBox guest additions installed and
> automatically loaded. You shouldn't need to install them again. If you
> upgrade to a newer kernel (but you haven't, you're running the stock
> kernel) then you might trip over the fact that VirtualBox isn't
> compatible yet with the newest kernels available and hence won't
> compile. That's not your issue I think.

And this *excerpt*

> Re: Virtualbox guest additions - installation problem
>
> by xenopeek on Thu Apr 25, 2013 2:56 am
>
> Miss Bit wrote:
>
> Do you mean that when I install a virtual Mint in VBox it knows that
> it is a VBox machine and then automatically install the guest
> additions?
>
> Well, not exactly. The VirtualBox guest additions are always
> installed, regardless of what you install Linux Mint on. When using it
> in VirtualBox it will load and use the guest additions automatically.
>
> The packages for this are virtualbox-guest-dkms,
> virtualbox-guest-utils, and virtualbox-guest-x11. Version 4.1.18
> should already be installed on your system, unless you removed it
> prior.